# Visual Studio, Team Explorer: Where are the work items

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

With Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 we used to manage and query work items directly from Team Explorer.

Probably it is something we did related to security or settings on the different VSO projects, but we lost visibility to the Work items

Don't want the question to sound stupid, but can't find any pointer how to fix and what is the reason that suddenly we lost this functionality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what are you looking for but if you start typing on "Quick Launch" text box you might find any option on VS. This feature is in the upper right corner. You can get it with CTRL + Q as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Under the Team Explorer, I used to have a view similar to the image in the Visual Studio link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500420.aspx but now I am only able to see: Changes, Branches Sync and Settings. Pull request and Work Items are no longer visible as well as the links to the Web portal and task board.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, found the issue. There was no signal that I need to re-authenticate... but anyway after entering credentials I am now able to see the web elements.

Thanks

Comment: Since the issue has been solved, you can mark it as answer.